Blazor WASM download large (>2GB) file from WEB API
I'm stucked... I've read all of the threads about this and can't make it work and don't know why...
I've a WEB API which should return a large zip file (>2GB), it creates the zip on disk, it's ok and returns with this:
return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(Path.Combine(<path_to_file>), FileMode.Open), "application/zip") { FileDownloadName = generatedFileName };

On the client side I've a Blazor WASM and getting the result this way:
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);                
request.Headers.Add("session", <session_data>);
... <other headers>
var result = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{      
    Console.WriteLine("Getting stream...");
    var responseStream = await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Stream done");
}


When the zip is relatively small (4-500MB) it works well, but when I try to download for example a 3 GB zip, the "Stream done" line never reached, instead of the I'm getting an error in the output:
"TypeError: Failed to fetch    at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpInterop.d__13`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpContent.GetResponseData(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpContent.CreateContentReadStreamAsync()
" and the line number where the ReadAsStreamAsync is.
What can be the problem here? Trying to solve it in the last two days but nothing helps...
Thanks!
I've tried everything :)

You can replace all your WASM code with just HttpClient.GetStreamAsync. The problem is what you do with that stream and how do you try to save the contents. If you use the common way of creating an Object URL you'll end up creating a copy of all 2GB of data in the browser's memory. Post the rest of the download code

As for the server code, use return File(path,"application/zip",generatedFileName) or return Results.File(path,"application/zip",generatedFileName) instead.

The result is the same as before

You haven't posted the full WASM code yet. If you try to use an Object URL it doesn't matter if GetStreamAsync works, the browser will end up storing 2*2GB in RAM and probably crash. I'm pretty sure I posted a comment saying to use an <a href='relative/path/to/file' download /> comment, because that will let the browser download the file directly. You can style the a link to look like a button

To check whether the error is due to networking issues, invalid request, timeout etc, use the Network tab in the browser's Developer Tools to see how the request progresses and whether it terminates abnormally. To ensure the server can send the file, type the file URI directly in the browser's address bar or add <a ... download> in the page to test the download.

Yes, the server can serve the file correctly, and through a regular link the browser downloads the file and it seems that's the only way to download such large files...
Thanks for your help!

Not quite and you still haven't posted the actual download code. In 2023 the File System API was finalized which allows scripts to save files to disk after prompting the user. There are some wrappers already, like this one. This is pretty new though and may not be available in your users' browsers. I'd still start with a download for now

That was exactly what I've done:
await using var stream = await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync(uri);
And after that CopyToAsync to a file system handle, but when the GetStreamAsync called the Network tab showed that it is downloading all the contents somewhere and failing at the end with the TypeError: Failed to fetch.
The client doesn't had the chance to copy the stream to the specified file system handle... the CopyToAsync never called

My guess is that you're running into a memory overflow. Maybe you can try streaming the file with JS Interop in chunks to prevent this.
Let's say your endpoint handler looks like this:
[HttpGet("download/{fileName}")]
public IActionResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(<path_to_file>, fileName);
    var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, bufferSize: 8192, useAsync: true);
    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/zip")
    {
        FileDownloadName = fileName
    };
}

Now on the client side app, since in Blazor WASM (as far as I know) directly saving a streamed response to a file is not supported/straightforward due to the lack of direct file system access. So we can use JS Interop for it.
For example:
//...
//rest of your code/ headers, etc...
//...
var response = await Http.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var fileName = "downloaded.zip"; // Change as needed
    await using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    await SaveFileFromStream(fileName, responseStream); //this is your saving method
}

For the SaveFileFromStream(fileName, responseStream) method:
private async Task SaveFileFromStream(string fileName, Stream stream)
{
    // Use JavaScript interop to save the file
    var jsStream = new DotNetStreamReference(stream);
    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("saveAsFile", fileName, jsStream);
}

For the saveAsFile JS function, this would be an example:
//this goes in your custom js file under /wwwroot/{yourJSFile}.js
//you need to reference it in /wwwroot/index.html

window.saveAsFile = async (fileName, streamRef) => {
        const arrayBuffer = await streamRef.arrayBuffer();
        const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
        anchorElement.href = url;
        anchorElement.download = fileName;
        anchorElement.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };


this line on the API side did the trick for a 1.5GB file (for this file I've got OutOfMemory before):
new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, bufferSize: 8192, useAsync: true);
but for the >3 GB file still getting the same error...

If I'm using ReadAsStream, without Async, I'm getting this, which I think totally nonsense
"Cannot write more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size: 2147483647.    at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBuffer(Int64 maxBufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CreateContentReadStream(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.ReadAsStream(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.ReadAsStream()"
If the MaxBufferSize is Int64 why limited to Int32.MaxValue???

You could try this below code:
Blazor project:
Index.html:
<script>
    async function downloadFileFromUrl(url) {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                'session': 'your_session_data' // Add other headers if needed
            }
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Failed to download file: ${response.statusText}`);
        }
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const urlBlob = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = urlBlob;
        a.download = 'new.zip';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        a.remove();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(urlBlob);
    }
</script>

DownloadFile.razor:
@page "/download-file"
   @inject IJSRuntime JS

<h3>Download Large File</h3>

<button @onclick="DownloadFileAsync">Download File</button>

@code {
    private async Task DownloadFileAsync()
    {
        var uri = "https://localhost:7089/api/FileDownload/download-large-file";
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromUrl", uri);
    }
   }

Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7089/") });

Webapi:
FileDownloadController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]

    public class FileDownloadController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("download-large-file")]
        public IActionResult DownloadLargeFile()
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine("file", "test.zip");
            var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/zip")
            {
                FileDownloadName = "new.zip"
            };
        }

    }
}

Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});



That's the plain vanilla download code that doesn't work with large files because it creates multiple copies of the file in memory

Getting a JSException: TypeError: Failed to fetch.
Stacktrace: at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpInterop.d__13`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()\r\nTypeError: Failed to fetch

@PanagiotisKanavos i have tested with 4 to 5 gb file size and it is not generating multiple files

@AttilaKiss could you share your updated code and error snapshot

I ended up with this, solved by a  and the browser handles the whole thing. Maybe in the future I will go back to this,  but it takes too much time now. Thanks for your help!

@AttilaKiss for your error just make sure you have added this cors code in the web application program.cs file: builder.Services.AddCors(options => {     options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",         builder =>         {             builder.AllowAnyOrigin()                    .AllowAnyMethod()                    .AllowAnyHeader();         }); });  and app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");  double check the url of the web application in the blazor component which we have added in the DownloadFile.razor file

Yes, all of these Cors parameters were set

@AttilaKiss from the web api you were able to download the file?

Yes, it works well!

@AttilaKiss you could share the updated code and the detailed error if you would like to troubleshoot the issue

There is no updated code, as I wrote before, I'm using a simple redirect to the URL for the file and browser handles the rest
